# 'for' loop through form fields and excluding one of the fields with 'if'

Tags: python, django-templates

I have:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% end for %}
```

What I want is to put an 'if' statement to exclude a field which .label or whatever is provided. Like:

```
{% for field in form%}
    {% if field == title %}
    {% else %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible? I have to many fields to write them one by one and only one or two to exclude.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% ifnotequal field.label title %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endifnotequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Django's [template tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ref-templates-builtins) offer `ifequal` and `ifnotequal` variants, and you can test the field.label against either a context variable, or a string.

Comment: Not that has been deprecated, so a simple {% if field.name == 'title' %} will work. Also comparing label is bad as it might change in translation.

Answer (score 7):

You might be a lot happier creating a subclass of the form, excluding the offending field.
See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#form-inheritance

```
class SmallerForm( MyForm ):
    class Meta(MyForm.Meta):
        exclude = [ title ]
```

Comment: +1. This is a better solution than {% if %}. Also I'd try using as_* rendering methods on form.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.name != 'field_name' %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Seems like this is the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: yeah, mostly same, But instead of // field.label title // i had to use // 'field_name' //. I hope this will help another django beginner like me.